# Select data between a date/time range

Tags: mysql, datetime

How do I select data between a date range in MySQL. My `datetime` column is in 24-hour zulu time format.

```
select * from hockey_stats 
where game_date between '11/3/2012 00:00:00' and '11/5/2012 23:59:00' 
order by game_date desc;
```

Returns nothing despite having data between these time periods. Do I have to force the values in the *'from'* and *'to'* fields to `datetime` type in the query?

Comment: What is the data-type for `game_date`?

Comment: its datetime. I think I figured out why I was confused. I am using *toad software* for mysql and by default it renders dates in the format I used in my date range, which is why I used the same. So the problem was the format of the date I supplied in my range.

Comment: If I use the format provided by Eugen Rieck it works as expected.

Comment: [How to select records where NOW is between two dates in fields?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/156848/143077), for those looking further

Answer (score 186, accepted):

You need to update the date format:

```
select * from hockey_stats 
where game_date between '2012-03-11 00:00:00' and '2012-05-11 23:59:00' 
order by game_date desc;
```

Comment: which one is the date and which one is the month here?

Comment: The format for a date literal is 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS'

Comment: Using BETWEEN is NOT best practice, especially since MySQL now supports **sub-second time precision**. Using 23:59:59 is one full second short of the end of a day.  `where game_date >= '2012-03-11' and game_date < '2012-05-12'` is the most precise way to define a date range and will work for any level of time precision from date to sub-second units.

Comment: @Used_By_Already When this was answered in 2013 there was no sub-second MySQL - an I have yet to hear of a hockey game starting between 23:59 and 00:00 with a sub-second start time.

Comment: It's for readers using MySQL versions with sub-second precision that I left this comment. MySQL version 5.6.4 or later supports fractional seconds.  (Regardles of which sport or purpose the date range is for.)

Comment: @Used_By_Already why is it not best practice? Would your example using the ">=" have better performance? Thank you.

Comment: It is for accuracy, not performance. As already mentioned 23:59:59 is not the end of a day. You avoid this issue neatly and precisely by using less than against the upper boundary of the date/time range. `where game_date >= '2012-03-11' and game_date < '2012-05-12'`

Answer (score 25):

Here is a simple way using the date function:

```
select *
from hockey_stats
where date(game_date) between date('2012-11-03') and date('2012-11-05')
order by game_date desc
```

Comment: Am I blind or is this a performance killer? `date(game_date)` will have the comparison run against a **calulcated value**, not a field  - resulting in no index use and every single row being touched (i.e. full table scan)!

Comment: @EugenRieck . . . You are right in general, assuming there is an index on `game_date`.  Even without an index, the table would have to be moderately sized for a noticeable difference in performance.  Something about the name `hockey_stats` suggests to me that this is not a really big table.

Answer (score 10):

**A simple way :**

```
select  * from  hockey_stats 
where  game_date >= '2012-03-11' and game_date  <= '2012-05-11'
```

Comment: this will fail if both dates are exactly same

Comment: @UmairAyub then you will need to validat e the input so you make sure that is values are not equal

Answer (score 7):

In a simple way it can be queried as

```
select * from hockey_stats 
where game_date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-31';
```

This works if time is not a concern.

Considering time also follow in the following way:

```
select * from hockey_stats where (game_date between '2018-02-05 01:20:00' and '2018-02-05 03:50:00');
```

Note this is for MySQL server.

Answer (score 5):

You probably need to use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```
select * from hockey_stats 
where
  game_date between STR_TO_DATE('11/3/2012 00:00:00', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s')
                and STR_TO_DATE('11/5/2012 23:59:00', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s') 
order by game_date desc;
```

(if game_date is a string, you might need to use STR_TO_DATE on it)

Answer (score 4):

MySQL date format is this : Y-M-D. You are using Y/M/D. That's is wrong. 
modify your query.

If you insert the date like Y/M/D, It will be insert null value in the database.

If you are using PHP and date you are getting from the form is like this Y/M/D, you can replace this with using the statement .

```
out_date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $data["input_date"])))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either user [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function and pass your own date parameters based on the format you have posted :

```
select * from hockey_stats where game_date 
  between STR_TO_DATE('11/3/2012 00:00:00', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s')
  and STR_TO_DATE('11/5/2012 23:59:00', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s') 
order by game_date desc;
```

Or just use the format which MySQL handles dates YYYY:MM:DD HH:mm:SS and have the query as

`select * from hockey_stats where game_date between '2012-03-11 00:00:00' and'2012-05-11 23:59:00' order by game_date desc;`

Answer (score 2):

You must search date defend on how you insert that game_date data on your database.. for example if you inserted date value on long date or short.

```
SELECT * FROM hockey_stats WHERE game_date >= "6/11/2018" AND game_date <= "6/17/2018"
```

You can also use *BETWEEN*:

```
SELECT * FROM hockey_stats WHERE game_date BETWEEN "6/11/2018" AND "6/17/2018"
```

simple as that.

Comment: I'm trying as same, but it's not working properly, getting random date-wise data.