# How to change the time with one day plus in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime, time

I am using CodeIgniter and I need to get daily sales details by date. Below is my MySQL query statement, and in it I need to take values everyday from 15:00:00 to 06:00:00 the next morning (ie, today's date is 29-9-2015, and for this result I need the data to be from 29-9-2015 15:00:00 to 30-9-2015 06:00:00).

I have tried so many ways. It is working only based on the daily hours from 15:00:00 to 24:00:00. If I give 06 instead of 24 then this does not work because the 06 is the next day's hour. I don't know how to +1 the day with hours in MySQL.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( date, '%e' ) AS date, SUM( COALESCE( total_tax, 0 ) ) AS tax1, SUM( COALESCE( total_tax2, 0 ) ) AS tax2, SUM( COALESCE( total, 0 ) ) AS total, SUM( COALESCE( inv_discount, 0 ) ) AS discount, SUM( COALESCE( cash_amt, 0 ) ) AS cash, SUM( COALESCE( master_amt, 0 ) ) AS master, SUM( COALESCE( visa_amt, 0 ) ) AS visa, SUM( COALESCE( nets_amt, 0 ) ) AS nets, SUM( COALESCE( coupon_amt, 0 ) ) AS coupon, SUM( COALESCE( paid, 0 ) ) AS paid FROM sales WHERE (DATE_FORMAT( date, '%Y-%m' ) = '2015-09') AND (DELETE_STATUS != 'Deleted') AND DATE_FORMAT( DATETIME, '%H' ) BETWEEN '15' AND '24' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT( DATETIME, '%e' );
```

I have attached my output screenshot with the result of 15 to 24 hours. I think you got my question.

[image]

Comment: select from date with time 15:00:00, and add 15hours in from date you will get **to** datetime

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821379/select-data-between-a-date-range

Comment: Today date is 29-9-2015, for this result need to come with 29-9-2015 15:00:00 to 30-9-2015 06:00:00. But here you cant mention the date in MySQL. Only mention time, this one is common for all date.

Comment: @Rob Quist: It is not duplicate, i am asking today time plus next day time come in a one day. Did you understand my question.

Comment: Yes, if you understood that duplicate question you could select today 15:00:00 to 06:00:00 the next day

Comment: I cant mention date in my query, because i m taking one month records with date based. If i give 15:00:00 to 06:00:00 means, my query not working. Because 06 is next day hours.

Comment: You can use the MySQL functions like NOW() to get the current date

Answer (score 1):

to add day(s) you need:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

to add hour(s) you need:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

You can also use DATE_SUB() instead of DATE_ADD() if you want to subtract instead of add time.

full manual here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: Today date is 29-9-2015, for this result need to come with 29-9-2015 15:00:00 to 30-9-2015 06:00:00. But here you cant mention the date in MySQL. Only mention time, this one is common for all date.

Comment: timestamp(expr1, expr2) allows you to create datetime value from separated date and time fields:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp

Comment: The date come with dynamically , i cant mention. But what i need exactly means, 15 to 06 (03pm to 06am) come with one day results. it will for hole month each days. Pls see my screenshot.

Comment: OK, so maybe you need sth like this:
SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 15 HOUR), DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 27 HOUR)
?

Comment: ok i got your comments. In that i took monthly result and group by date. if i give date(now()) means current date only display.

Comment: But i need current month of every date results.