# How to fetch mysql data between one month to another month

Tags: mysql, datetime, fetch

I am looking for query which fetch data between two months.

Like 1 January to  1 May or 1 June to 1 September etc

Thanks,
Ali

Comment: [This is a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821379/select-data-between-a-date-range).  That's just one example, I'm pretty sure this question has probably been asked many times and could be found with a simple google search.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE dateColumn >= "2016-01-01" AND dateColumn <= "2016-06-01";
```

You could find this easily on Google.

Comment: Thanks for your help I tried google before posting here.
I have a time stamp will it work with time stamp? because time stamp has other format than this.

Comment: Yes. It works with timestamp as well, using the same logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with a `TIMESTAMP` column you need to be careful about the end of your selected time interval.  Let's say you want everything in the first five months of 2016: 1-Jan-2016 -- 31-May-2016. Then you must select all the timestamps starting with midnight on the first day of the range, up until but not including midnight on the day *after* the range. That looks like this

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table
 WHERE timestampColumn >= '2016-01-01'
   AND timestampColumn <  '2016-06-01'
```

Notice the `<` on the end-date condition.

Why?  The timestamp constant `2016-05-31` actually means `2016-05-31 00:00:00`: or precisely midnight at the beginning of the day in question. So, an entry in your `timestampColumn` of, for example `2016-05-31 08:45:00` will not be matched by

```
   timestampColumn <= '2016-05-31'
```