# php return stops the loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

good day I write a function where I want to display the records which will match on the dates last week but it only loop one time. Is there a way to return all the dates and show all the records that will match with the dates? Here is my code.

```
function fetch_week(){

$today = date('F d Y');

for($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++)
{
    $repeat = strtotime("-1 day",strtotime($today));
    $today = date('F d Y',$repeat);
    $output = '';
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sample");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM list WHERE datee = '".$today."' ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if(empty(mysqli_num_rows($result))){
    echo '<td colspan="6"><h5><center>NO RECORDS.</center></h5></td>';
    }
    else{

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $output .= '<tbody id="appTable">
                <tr class="content" style="font-weight: normal text-align: center">  
                      <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>  
                      <td>'.$row["address"].'</td> 
                      <td>'.$row["contact"].'</td>
                      <td>'.$row["datee"].'</td> 
                </tr>  
             </tbody>
                      ';

    }
    return $output;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you don't need a for loop you can do this with the query select date range .related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821379/select-data-between-a-date-time-range/15821412

Comment: Hi, thankyou for the response. I want to ask if that is working if the date format is like February 24 2019.

Comment: not sure but you can convert date strings to correct date format  before run the query `strtotime`

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array and return that after your loop ends. Check below code:

```
function fetch_week() {

    $today = date('F d Y');
    $response = [];
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++) {
        $repeat = strtotime("-1 day", strtotime($today));
        $today = date('F d Y', $repeat);
        $output = '';
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sample");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM list WHERE datee = '" . $today . "' ORDER BY id DESC";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if (empty(mysqli_num_rows($result))) {
            echo '<td colspan="6"><h5><center>NO RECORDS.</center></h5></td>';
        } else {
            $output = '<tbody id="appTable">';
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                $output .= '<tr class="content" style="font-weight: normal text-align: center">  
                      <td>' . $row["name"] . '</td>  
                      <td>' . $row["address"] . '</td> 
                      <td>' . $row["contact"] . '</td>
                      <td>' . $row["datee"] . '</td> 
                </tr>';
            }
            $output .= '</tbody>';
            $response[] = $output;
        }
    }
    return $response;
}
```

You need to loop through on output to print your data. But apart from all these, your code is widely open for SQL injection. Please be careful and do changes for that. Also you don't need to create tbody again and again in loop. You can do that first time only which I have changed in above code as well.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thankyou for your comment, but is this code only works with an interger?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking with integer value. But can you show me what your column type of datee field in your database? You may need to change date format as `$today = date('Y-m-d', $repeat);`

Comment: The type is in varchar. Sorry with my question I ask it because I get a notice saying Notice: Array to string conversion.

Comment: on which line, you are having this issue?

Comment: On the part of the if statement

Comment: that if statement seems fine but you can set no record condition in $response array and can return that as well. Your code is little buggy. You can connect with me over Skype rohit.mittal54 where I can help you better :)